# How to know if I Won the lottery In C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

So, I'm trying to make something to check if won the lottery automatically.

This game i'm playing has 25 numbers, you can choose 15.

if you hit 15 numbers, you win! (it doesn't need to be in the sequence)

I have a list with all the games called: 'TodosJogos'
and my gamble called: 'Jogado'

Now, I'm doing in this way: (which I think it's a terrible one)

```
 private void VerificaVitoria(Jogo Jogado, string TipoJogo)
        {
            bool Ganhou;
            List<Jogo> LstClassificadas = new List<Jogo>();

            LstClassificadas = TodosJogos.Where(x => x.N1 == Jogado.N1 ||
                x.N1 == Jogado.N2 ||
                x.N1 == Jogado.N3 ||
                x.N1 == Jogado.N4 ||
                x.N1 == Jogado.N5 ||
                x.N1 == Jogado.N6 ||
                x.N1 == Jogado.N7 ||
                x.N1 == Jogado.N8 ||
                x.N1 == Jogado.N9 ||
                x.N1 == Jogado.N10 ||
                x.N1 == Jogado.N11 ||
                x.N1 == Jogado.N12 ||
                x.N1 == Jogado.N13 ||
                x.N1 == Jogado.N14 ||
                x.N1 == Jogado.N15).ToList<Jogo>();

            LstClassificadas = LstClassificadas.Where(x => x.N2 == Jogado.N1 ||
               x.N2 == Jogado.N2 ||
               x.N2 == Jogado.N3 ||
               x.N2 == Jogado.N4 ||
               x.N2 == Jogado.N5 ||
               x.N2 == Jogado.N6 ||
               x.N2 == Jogado.N7 ||
               x.N2 == Jogado.N8 ||
               x.N2 == Jogado.N9 ||
               x.N2 == Jogado.N10 ||
               x.N2 == Jogado.N11 ||
               x.N2 == Jogado.N12 ||
               x.N2 == Jogado.N13 ||
               x.N2 == Jogado.N14 ||
               x.N2 == Jogado.N15).ToList<Jogo>();

            LstClassificadas = LstClassificadas.Where(x => x.N3 == Jogado.N1 ||
                 x.N3 == Jogado.N2 ||
                 x.N3 == Jogado.N3 ||
                 x.N3 == Jogado.N4 ||
                 x.N3 == Jogado.N5 ||
                 x.N3 == Jogado.N6 ||
                 x.N3 == Jogado.N7 ||
                 x.N3 == Jogado.N8 ||
                 x.N3 == Jogado.N9 ||
                 x.N3 == Jogado.N10 ||
                 x.N3 == Jogado.N11 ||
                 x.N3 == Jogado.N12 ||
                 x.N3 == Jogado.N13 ||
                 x.N3 == Jogado.N14 ||
                 x.N3 == Jogado.N15).ToList<Jogo>();

            //.....

            Ganhou = LstClassificadas.Count > 0 ? true : false;


            if (Ganhou)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You won in the game: " + TipoJogo);
            }

        }
```

It's the similar to this query:

```
select * from jogos
where n1 in(8,18,16,7,5,20,9,6,10,17,22,3,14,21,15)
and n2 in(8,18,16,7,5,20,9,6,10,17,22,3,14,21,15)
and n3 in(8,18,16,7,5,20,9,6,10,17,22,3,14,21,15)
and n4 in(8,18,16,7,5,20,9,6,10,17,22,3,14,21,15)
and n5 in(8,18,16,7,5,20,9,6,10,17,22,3,14,21,15)
and n6 in(8,18,16,7,5,20,9,6,10,17,22,3,14,21,15)
and n7 in(8,18,16,7,5,20,9,6,10,17,22,3,14,21,15)
and n8 in(8,18,16,7,5,20,9,6,10,17,22,3,14,21,15)
and n9 in(8,18,16,7,5,20,9,6,10,17,22,3,14,21,15)
and n10 in(8,18,16,7,5,20,9,6,10,17,22,3,14,21,15)
and n11 in(8,18,16,7,5,20,9,6,10,17,22,3,14,21,15)
and n12 in(8,18,16,7,5,20,9,6,10,17,22,3,14,21,15)
and n13 in(8,18,16,7,5,20,9,6,10,17,22,3,14,21,15)
and n14 in(8,18,16,7,5,20,9,6,10,17,22,3,14,21,15)
and n15 in(8,18,16,7,5,20,9,6,10,17,22,3,14,21,15)
```

**Is there any better way to do it?**

Comment: I suggest reading up on bogosorts http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from your SQL query, I think this is what you want:

```
var lotteryNumbers = new int[] { ... };
var results =
    from j in jogos
    where lotteryNumbers.Contains(j.n1) &&
          lotteryNumbers.Contains(j.n2) &&
          lotteryNumbers.Contains(j.n3) &&
          lotteryNumbers.Contains(j.n4) &&
          lotteryNumbers.Contains(j.n5) &&
          lotteryNumbers.Contains(j.n6) &&
          lotteryNumbers.Contains(j.n7) &&
          lotteryNumbers.Contains(j.n8) &&
          lotteryNumbers.Contains(j.n9) &&
          lotteryNumbers.Contains(j.n10) &&
          lotteryNumbers.Contains(j.n11) &&
          lotteryNumbers.Contains(j.n12) &&
          lotteryNumbers.Contains(j.n13) &&
          lotteryNumbers.Contains(j.n14) &&
          lotteryNumbers.Contains(j.n15)
    select j;
```

Or in fluent syntax

```
var results =
    jogos.Where(j =>
          lotteryNumbers.Contains(j.n1) &&
          lotteryNumbers.Contains(j.n2) &&
          lotteryNumbers.Contains(j.n3) &&
          lotteryNumbers.Contains(j.n4) &&
          lotteryNumbers.Contains(j.n5) &&
          lotteryNumbers.Contains(j.n6) &&
          lotteryNumbers.Contains(j.n7) &&
          lotteryNumbers.Contains(j.n8) &&
          lotteryNumbers.Contains(j.n9) &&
          lotteryNumbers.Contains(j.n10) &&
          lotteryNumbers.Contains(j.n11) &&
          lotteryNumbers.Contains(j.n12) &&
          lotteryNumbers.Contains(j.n13) &&
          lotteryNumbers.Contains(j.n14) &&
          lotteryNumbers.Contains(j.n15));
```

Although this assumes you don't have duplicates in either `lotteryNumbers` or in `j.n1 .. j.n15`. Otherwise you'd probably get unexpected results.

Comment: Would you help me to translate that to Lambda?

Comment: @Moondustt: `from a in b where c select d` is translated into `b.Where(a=>c).Select(a=>d)`.

Answer (score 32):

Two ways to solve your problem.

Represent a winning combination as a set of fifteen integers:

```
HashSet<int>
```

You have a sequence of winning games:

```
IEnumerable<HashSet<int>>
```

and a specific `HashSet<int>`. You wish to know if the specific set exactly matches any of the winning sets.

### Method One

```
static bool DidIWin(IEnumerable<HashSet<int>> winningNumbers, HashSet<int> myNumbers)
{
    return winningNumbers
      .Where(winningNumber => myNumbers.SetEquals(winningNumber))
      .Any();
}
```

Or even

```
static bool DidIWin(IEnumerable<HashSet<int>> winningNumbers, HashSet<int> myNumbers)
{
    return winningNumbers
      .Any(winningNumber => myNumbers.SetEquals(winningNumber));
}
```

### Method Two

```
static bool DidIWin(IEnumerable<HashSet<int>> winningNumbers, HashSet<int> myNumbers)
{
    return false;
}
```

*Method two is a lot faster*. However, it gives the incorrect result on average one time out of every three million winning numbers. This demonstrates that sometimes you can get a big performance win by being willing to accept a tiny amount of inaccuracy.

:-)

Comment: AHHAHAHAHAHAH, NICE MATE, liked your sense of humor =) and the method is very clean!